# Spark Streaming - Accessing an array of custom case class objects in a Spark SQL dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In my Spark Streaming query I would like to use a case class called URL with 3 string members as follows:

```
  url: string            
  domain: string         
  topLevelDomain: string
```

I would like to create a `DataFrame` where one of the members is an array of URL objects. Schema as follows:

```
root
 |-- AccountId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- url1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- topLevelDomain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- finalURLs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- topLevelDomain: string (nullable = true)
```

The column `finalURLs` is an array of URL objects.

Later, I would like to apply a transformation on this column to convert it to a list of strings which can either be `domain` or `topLevelDomain` depending on the values in the other columns.

First of all, is it possible to have a column which is an array of case class objects ? If yes, how can the above transformation be applied to reduce it to an array of strings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use case-classes, you need to convert the DataFrame to a dataset. If you do so, you need to convert the entire record, not just the URL. Something like this would work :

```
case class URL(url:String, domain:String, topLevelDomain:String)
case class MyRow(AccountId:Int, url1:URL, finalURLs:Seq[URL])

df.as[MyRow].map{case MyRow(accountId,url1,finalURLs) => (accountId,url1,finalURLs.map{case URL(url,domain,topLevelDomain) => /*your logic here*/ })}
```